# Reading a UTF-8 File in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, utf-8, binaryreader

I have this file, it uses UTF-8 encoding and I am trying to read it. So far, I've used BinaryReader, FileStream, I tried File.ReadAllLines. So far, I'm only getting the first line of the file.

Here is some samples of what I've tried so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string filename = @"C:\UNICORN\Server\Fil\Users30.mpm";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void clearText(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            rtb.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a binary reader
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int length = (int) br.BaseStream.Length;    // length of the file
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

                for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    bytes[i] = br.ReadByte();
                }
                sb.Append("File Size: " + bytes.Length + "\n");
                sb.AppendLine(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a binary reader
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int length = (int) br.BaseStream.Length;

                sb.Append("File Size: " + length + "\n");
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    var v = br.ReadInt32();
                    sb.Append((char)v + "\n");
                    pos += sizeof (int);
                }

                richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a binary reader
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;    // length of the file
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

                sb.Append("File Size: " + bytes.Length + "\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    var b = br.ReadByte();
                    sb.Append("Byte: " + b + " - " + (char) b + "\n");
                }

                //sb.AppendLine(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a stream reader
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sb.Append(sr.ReadLine() + "\n");
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a stream reader
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
            {
                while(!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if(line != null)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use a file stream and a decoder
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] byData = new byte[255];
            char[] charData = new char[255];
            try
            {
                FileStream aFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
                aFile.Seek(55, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                aFile.Read(byData, 0, 100);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sb.Append("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            }

            Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            d.GetChars(byData, 0, byData.Length, charData, 0);

            foreach(char c in charData)
            {
                sb.Append(c + " ");
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // find the encoding of a file, just trying to find out the encoding with this
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using(var r = new StreamReader(filename, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
            {
                var es = r.CurrentEncoding;
                sb.Append("Encoding: " + es);
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // use File.ReadAllLines()
            clearText(richTextBox1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sb.Append(line.ToString() + "\n");
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

All of these examples only show me one line of the file. How would you go about reading/parsing the whole file?

The file contains a list of users and I'm ultimately trying to read the file to find those user names. Right now, it's only showing the first line of the file which is "UNICORN 3.06".

Comment: If it is UTF-8 encoding it is a text file, not a binary file. Also if it is UTF-8 why are you using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(` instead of `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(`?

Comment: I used ASCII when I didn't know it was UTF-8 and didn't bother to change it back yet. I'm having trouble with this for some reason. I changed that line of code to UTF8 and it still only reads the first line of the file.

Comment: If this is a text file and not really a binary file and you want to just the text of the file all as a string I would use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that now. Thanks. Also, I changed the title since "Binary" is now kind of misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ReadByte should have a len position in its constructor
but:

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(byte b in fileBytes)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));  // adds 8 '0's to left of the string
}

File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I use that to find a user name or some other piece of information in the file?

Comment: user name? you want to look at the file in ASCI text only then. if the user is even stored in their that way.  Otherwise you would need to know what byte the username starts at, and how they are encoding it.  now your going into reverse engineering.  that's a whole other animal which I am very familiar with >=]

Comment: I did do some figuring out and found out the distance between the first character of the first line to the first character of the user name. I also found out that there is an equal distance between the first character of each user name in the file.

Comment: Also, I figured it out. I was able to get the info I needed from the file!

Comment: @user: When you talk about "distance" in the file, are you counting bytes or characters? A character in an UTF-8 encoded file can be one or more bytes.

Comment: @guffa: i used a hex viewer to see the addresses of the particular info I was looking for and started from the address of the first character. I figured it out and can read the file now.

Comment: @user: Ok, just note that the address is in bytes, so you need to read the files into a byte array, then decode parts of the array into text. If you decode the entire file into text, the character indexes may differ from the byte indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the text, the `ReadAllText` method reads an entire file as utf-8:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }
```

If you also want information about the file length, read the file as bytes and decode it as utf-8:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        richTextBox1.Text = "File size: " + data.Length + "\r\n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but when I tried using File.ReadAllText() it only shows the first line of the file. Maybe there's something wrong with my file. The file size is correct but the text is too short. It's supposed to be 1,144kb and it is but there's only a small amount of text displayed in the rich text box.

Comment: @user: Then it's likely that's there something wrong with the file. Are you sure that it's a text file? Anyway, you can add `.bin` to the file name and open the file in Visual Studio, then you can see exactly what's in it.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that. I'll try opening it in visual studio. I'm pretty sure it's a text file. But it does have some weird characters in it. The problem is that it's proprietary to some company and they wont tell me how they parse it.

Comment: I just checked it out in visual studio, I can definitely see all the data in it. I may have messed up my code so I'm going to look into it some more